# R check character values for numeric and change var datatype automatically

Tags: r, string, numeric

I have many dataframes where all the data is character.  I can guess that a var containing a number should be changed to a numeric data type.  I have 100's of columns though so I don't want to type out each each one to change in order to change it.
Is there another way to automate this process and to scan a column of data check if the character has a numeric value and change it into a numeric type from character type?

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c("21000", "23400", "26800")
gender <- c("M", "M", "F")
rank <- c("5", "109", "2")

df <- data.frame(employee, salary, gender, rank)
```

I don't want to have to do this for each column/var

```
df$rank <- as.numeric(df$rank)
```

I would like to do something like this

```
i <- sapply(df, is.vector.of.columns.contaning.numeric.values)
df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write a function with the number condition. It works by trying `as.numeric` and checking if it returns `NA`, if it does, that means the value cannot be coerced to an unambiguous numeric. When this happens, the function will keep the column as is.

```
smartConvert <-  function(x) {
  if(any(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x))))) x else as.numeric(x)
}

df[] <- lapply(df, smartConvert)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ employee: Factor w/ 3 levels "John Doe","Jolie Hope",..: 1 3 2
#  $ salary  : num  1 2 3
#  $ gender  : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 1
#  $ rank    : num  3 1 2
```

Comment: I was going down the similar `sapply(names(df), function(x)  any(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df[, x])))))` route